# Error con un identificador

Tags: c++

> ```
> note: jump bypasses initialization of variable length array int arr1[num];
>
> tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'num'
> int arr1[num];
>          ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Hola estoy haciendo un programa donde debo ordenar un arreglo pero no puedo declarar el arreglo.

El programa funciona cuando borro la línea donde declaro `arr1[num];`.

Supongo que no puedo declarar un arreglo dentro de un *switch* pero no tiene sentido porque puedo declarar `arr[num]` sin errores.

```
    switch(opc)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            cout << "CAPTURA DE DATOS: " << endl;
            cout << "\nRango [1,100]" << endl;
            cout << "\xc2\xbf" << "Cu\xc3\xa1ntos elementos se ordenar\xc3\xa1n? ";
            cin >> num;
            while(cin.fail() || num < 1 || num > 100)
            {
                cout << "La cardinalidad no puede ser negativa, y su m\xc3\xa1ximo es 100, intntelo de nuevo..." << endl;
                cout << "\nRango [1,100]" << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
                cout << "\xc2\xbf" << "Cu\xc3\xa1ntos elementos se ordenar\xc3\xa1n? ";
                cin >> num;
            }

            cout << "\nM\xc3\xa9todos de llenado:" << endl;
            cout << "\t0. Al azar" << endl;
            cout << "\t1. Captura manual" << endl;
            cout << "\n\xc2\xbf" << "C\xc3\xb3mo desea obtener los datos? ";
            cin >> como;
            while(como < 0 || como > 1)
            {
                cout << "Opci\xc3\xb3n fuera de rango... Intente de nuevo.";
                cout << "\n\n\xc2\xbf" << "C\xc3\xb3mo desea obtener los datos? ";
                cin >> como;
            }
            switch(como)
            {
                case 0:
                    int arr1[num];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    int arr[num];
                    cout << "Los valores deben ser positivos y a lo m\xc3\xa1s 20";
                    cout << "\n\n";
                    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                    {
                        cout << "Elemento [" << (i+1) << "] = ";
                        cin >> arr[i];
                    }
                    
                    break;
            } 
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes declarar lo que quieras dentro de `switch`, simplemente añade un ámbito con unas llaves (`{` y `}`):

```
case 0:
    {
        int arr1[num];
    }
    break;
case 1:
    {
        int arr[num];
    }
    break;
```

Pero entonces `arr1` y `arr` existirán sólo en ese ámbito, que supongo que no es lo que quieres, así que tu única opción es crear el arreglo fuera del `switch`.

Por otro lado, en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no se pueden crear en memoria automática arreglos cuyo tamaño sea una variable, el tamaño debe ser una constante. Así que olvídate de esto:

```
case 0:
    {
        int arr1[num];
    //           ^^^ <--- Esto es una variable, no se puede.
    }
    break;
case 1:
    {
        int arr[num];
    //          ^^^ <--- Esto es una variable, no se puede.
    }
    break;
```

No te queda más remedio que usar un `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> arr;

switch(como)
{
case 0:
    arr.resize(num);
    break;
case 1:
    arr.resize(num);
    cout << "Los valores deben ser positivos y a lo m\xc3\xa1s 20";
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Elemento [" << (i+1) << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    break;
}
```